# How to initialize priority_queue of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am trying to initialize a priority_queue  , Here is the code

```
class stdnt{
    public:
        int indx;
        int c;
        int lvl;
    bool operator<(const stdnt &x)
    {
        return this->c > x.c;
    }
};
priority_queue<stdnt> pq;
```

But its giving me error that passing const & discards qualifiers. How else am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the operator `const` so that it can be called on `const` instances or via `const` references or pointers to `const`:

```
    bool operator<(const stdnt &x) const
                                   ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, make it a non-member:

```
bool operator<(const stdnt &lhs, const stdnt& rhs)
{
    return lhs.c > rhs.c;
}
```